# When is there a need to use implements Iterable<T>

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am writing a generic class SortedGroup so that the generic type `implements Comparable<T>`. The class signature is

`public class SortedGroup<T extends Comparable<T>>`.

I need to write a method that returns an iterator of the generic type.

The question is:

Is there a need to write the class signature with implements Iterable like:

`public class SortedGroup<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T>`

or i can write it without `implements Iterable<T>`?

It is not clear to me because i don't get any error writing it with or without the

`implements Iterable<T>`.

**EDIT:** The class is using ArrayList to store the data. So I am using its iterator method.

Is the method written below correct?

```
public Iterator<T> iterator()
{
    return list.iterator();
}
```

Comment: If you want proper handling by java (e.g. for-each-loops) you have to add `implements Iterable<T>`. Java will **not** accept the `iterator()` method if it is not from the interface, even when it has the matching signature. Keyword here is "statically typed language"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: if you want that your "collection" can be looped the same way as any other standard java collection, then you better have `implements Iterable<T>` on your class.

The point is: having that interface allows users to do this:

```
for (Bar foo : someSortedGroupOfBars) {
```

In other words: only when you are absolutely sure that your groups shall **never** be iterated using "standard" Java patterns, then you consider not implementing that interface when implementing some sort of "container".

You might even go one step further and decide whether implementing `Collection` or an even more specialized interface such as `List` makes sense! Doing so of course requires you to implement more methods (which kinda all make sense for a "group container" imho).

Beyond that, it mainly depends on your context. If you are writing this class for a very specific task (maybe an exercise in school), then: write the *minimum* amount of code that does what you need. Then it might be the right thing to *not* implement an interface you don't need. But as soon as this class is supposed to exist for "more than that", then implementing the interface is a very natural and straight forward idea.

And answering the other question asked: "delegating" to the iterator of the underlying ArrayList is a valid approach.

Comment: @AndyTurner You can't add, but you can definitely remove using an iterator.

Comment: @Michael you can't remove from an Iterable: you remove from the *Iterator*. My point is that "any other Collection" has a `remove` method.

Comment: @AndyTurner Basically all an iterable is is a supplier for an iterator. So I'd say you definitely *can* remove from an iterable, since removing from its iterator will mean subsequently issued iterators do not include the removed item.

Comment: @Michael you can't remove from an Iterable *in the same way* as you can from a Collection.

Comment: @GhostCat [oh](http://www.dictionary.com/e/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/triggered-2.png)